# Make VueI18n react to router link tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I have this Vue app which is composed of a simple home page, a title, and a home text. You can view this app online on my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pba7mek/1/). Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  My header app
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const Home = {
    template: `
      <div>
        <h1>{{ $t('home.title') }}</h1>
        <p v-html="$t('home.text')"></p>
      </div>
    `
};

const messages = {
    en: {
    home: {
        title: 'Hello world',
        text: 'Find all post by clicking <router-link to="/post">this link</router-link>!'
    }
  }
};

const routes = [
    { name: 'home', path: '*', component: Home }
];

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: messages
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});

const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    i18n: i18n
});
```

**Problem**

As you can see, there is no "router-link" link visible, and clicking the link will not redirect to the desired route.

**Question**

Is it possible to make VueI18n interpret `<router-link>` tag inside a `v-html` directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-html` replaces content of an element with a [plain HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML), so custom elements used inside a replacing string are not compiled to Vue.js components.

You may want to check component interpolation way suggested by [VueI18n documentation](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#basic-usage), that involves usage of `i18n` functional component and template strings.

Here is the fork of the provided fiddle that implements this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/u5vx1mLq/

In a nutshell, `i18n` component has `path` prop into which you can path a template string and `tag` prop which defines a tag, `i18n` component is to be replaced with. `i18n` also has a slot, which can be used to define a child component within which you can interpolate partials of the template string.

Sorry for the awkward explanation, hopefully the code snippet will shed some light on this matter:

```
const Home = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>{{ $t('home.title') }}</h1>
      <i18n path="home.linkLabel" tag="label" for="home.linkText">
        <router-link to="/post">{{ $t('home.linkText') }}</router-link>
      </i18n>
    </div>
  `
};

const messages = {
  en: {
    home: {
      title: 'Hello world',
      linkText: 'this link',
      linkLabel: 'Find all post by clicking {0}'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Very instructive, I also like the variant using named interpolation parts.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, named formatting is great, especially when there are multiple parts.

Answer (score 1):

A few things changed since antonku's excellent answer

https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html

A tag like

```
<i18n-t keypath="mymessage">xxx</i18n-t>
```

will output the translation of `mymessage` and `xxx` is sent as a parameter for that message

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    mymessage: 'here are some characters: {0}'
  }
};
```

More elaborate, this tag takes two links as input and renders the output in a `small` tag

```
<i18n-t keypath="twolinks" tag="small">
   <template v-slot:link1>
     <a href="//link1.nl/" target="_blank">here</a>
   </template>
   <template v-slot:link2>
     <router-link :to="{ name: 'login' }">here</router-link>
   </template>
</i18n-t>
```

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    twolinks: 'I want you to click {link1} and then {link2}'
  }
};
```